# Data formatting in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to convert my table into a sql formula, since i got 100+ cols in my table it has become a nerve wrecking task for me to do it manually. Hence i'm depending on excel for some help

table

| A |
| --- |
| name |
| lastname |
| age |
| address2 |
| address3 |

I want the the above content turn into excel formula format. like:

```
new( x1.[name], x2.[name], x3.[name], x4.[name], x5.[name] ) as [name]
```

I'm looking for a excel formula that could help me with this string transformation.

what i tried

```
="new""(""x1""."&A.........."x5""."&A")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to concatenate text with a cell's value with something like this `"some text ["&A1&"] some more"`

```
"new( x1.["&A1&"], x2.["&A2&"], x3.["&A3&"] [...] x5."& ) as ["&A1&"]"
```

Comment: thank you! but how can i add the square braces around A1

Comment: by including it in the text, I added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn’t notice it was EXCEL2010

[image]

```
="new( "&TEXTJOIN("，",,TEXT(ROW($1:$9),"x0\.\[")&A1:A9&"name]")&" ) as [name]"
```

or

```
="new( "&TEXTJOIN("，",,TEXT(ROW($1:$9),"x0\.\[")&A1:A9&"]")&" ) as "&A1
```